# Plugin like the "I Love It" Theme?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I'm looking for a plugin that allows users to give a 'thumbs up' or otherwise say they like a post.  Additionally, I want to be able to display a graphic with the number of likes/loves/'thumbs ups' when the posts are shown in a list.

This theme seems to have the functionality I am looking for:

http://themeforest.net/item/i-love-it-content-sharing-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/698475

A user can click the heart to say they 'love' the post, the number of people who 'love' the post is shown in the excerpt as well.

Our website has Product Reviews and Recipes, and I'm wanting to find a plugin (or code, if need be) that will allow people to say, "Yes, I've tried this and love it too!".  Then in the grid-layout of posts (of both Product Reviews and Recipes), users would be able to see how many others like those specific products or recipes.

Is there a plugin out there that would allow me to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [**`Love It`**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/love-it/) which is a very new plugin that adds a "Love It" link to your posts, pages, and custom post types. It works similar to Facebook's Like button, but is exclusive to your website. Its based on [this tutorial](http://pippinsplugins.com/write-a-love-it-plugin-with-ajax/) by Pippin.

Comment: Thank you, after you recommended this I actually got in touch with Pippin, and he provided me instructions to hopefully do what I need to (as far as the php to call to make the count visible per post).  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something really similer or even the same if

you take the time to change images using GD Star Rating**

here is a link: [gd-star-rating](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/gd-star-rating/)

Please note that it is a complex plguin that require 
a lot of settings to achive the desired look..

Cheers, Sagive

Comment: Thank you, I had seen this but didn't know it was so configurable.  I think I will try the new Love It plugin, and if that doesn't work, I will try and configure the GD Star Rating plugin.  Thank you so much!